# PHP Modify the return of a loop over and over

Tags: php

Basically I want to do a php loop that base64_encodes its self 5 times.

//For example
i want to encode "test" which is "dGVzdA=="
then we encode "dGVzdA==" which is "ZEdWemRBPT0="
then encode "ZEdWemRBPT0=" which is "WkVkV2VtUkJQVDA9"

I can't figure out how to create a loop that modifies its self each time it runs.

```
// this is what i had

function enloop($dowork){
    for ($i=1; $i&lt;=5; $i++)
    {
        return base64_encode($dowork);
    }
}
enloop($code);
```

THIS SCRIPT just repeats the encode 5 times, lets say your encodign the word test for example the output would be dGVzdA==dGVzdA==dGVzdA==dGVzdA==dGVzdA==

this is not what i want.

Comment: Doing base64 encode 5 times is just stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function enloop($dowork)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    {
        $dowork = base64_encode($dowork);
    }

    return $dowork;
}

enloop($code);
```

Comment: Seriously "zerkms" thats all it was, a matter of putting return outside of the for loop, god, lol thanks man.